# Is it possible to use C++20 modules in bazel with custom rules?

Tags: c++, bazel, c++20, c++-modules

Bazel does not have direct support for modules (See [Issue #4005](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4005)).

However, it is possible to provide bazel with a custom CROSSTOOL.

From https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.22.0/crosstool-reference.html:

> By default, Bazel automatically configures CROSSTOOL for your build, but you have the option to configure it manually.

And it's possible to extend bazel with custom rules.

From https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html:

> A few rules are built into Bazel itself. These native rules, such as cc_library and java_binary, provide some core support for certain languages. By defining your own rules, you can add similar support for languages and tools that Bazel does not support natively.

And this [comment](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4005#issuecomment-341682670) on Bazel's module issue suggests that you can use a custom CROSSTOOL to support modules even without native support:

> everything regarding modules (only for clang) is open sourced already. The only missing piece is a CROSSTOOL that makes use of them and provides all necessary features.

Could anyone show how to write a custom CROSSTOOL for clang and how you can use it to write a custom C++ rule for modules (e.g. `cc_module`) so that you can do things like this:

Write a basic module

```cpp
// helloworld.cc
module;
#include <stdio.h>

export module helloworld;
export void hello();

module :private;
void hello() { puts("Hello world!"); }
```

Use the module

```cpp
// main.cc
import helloworld;
int main() { hello(); }
```

Integrate the parts into the build system

```py
cc_module(
   name = "helloworld",
   srcs = ["helloworld.cc"],
) # Compiles to a precomiled module file (PCM)

cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = [
    "main.cc",
  ],
  deps = [
     ":helloworld",
   ],
) # Compiles against the helloworld PCM
```

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for SO's format. Are you looking for a tutorial or something?

Comment: Also, please make sure to tag C++ questions with [tag:c++] in addition to language version tags.

Comment: @cigien - I don't believe it is. I'm looking for how to set up a basic project that uses modules.

Comment: That's 1) not trivial and 2) at least according to the issue I linked possible using a custom CROSSTOOL

Comment: Please explain why that's not a fit for SO

Comment: I agree it's not trivial. But I do feel it's too broad for an answer. Not to worry, it seems I'm the only one to have voted to close, so if others don't, the question stays open :)

Comment: Bazel has a basic vocabulary for defining C++ constructs such as binaries and libraries. There's a natural way that modules would fit into the build system (e.g. some sort of command like cc_module). How to write such a cc_module command in skylark and have it forward the correct options to the compiler would be a legitimate answer to this question.

Comment: Aah, now if your last comment was part of the question, I'd much more inclined to retract my vote. That's a much more focused question.

Comment: @cigien - I edit the question to clarify that I'm looking for some sort of C++ rule that can be used to produce and integrate precompiled module files into the build system.

Comment: Ok, it might still be too broad, but I'm satisfied enough to retract my close vote. Thanks for the edits :)

Comment: For now, you can't. That's why the bug is open. Patience, young grasshopper. Voting to close - talk to people on the bug page. If you're implementing a mechanism to do this, yourself - ask a more specific question.

Comment: @einpoklum - it's possible to use a custom written CROSSTOOL with bazel. This [comment](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4005#issuecomment-341682670) from one of the core developers suggests that you could use such a custom CROSSTOOL to support modules. Do you disagree with him?

Comment: @einpoklum - The bug is open because it's not easy and I'm sure they plan direct support. But bazel is extensible and I haven't seen anything that says it's not possible.

Comment: I clearly outlined the mechanism I'm looking for to use modules (a custom CROSSTOOL + custom rule). Bazel is designed to be extensible and I haven't seen anything that says modules can't be supported by bazel's extension framework. If people think the custom CROSSTOOL/rule framework is insufficient, please explain why. Otherwise, I see this as a legitimate question.

Comment: This is legitimate question for Bazel usage and a how-to for Starlark rule extensions. Voted to reopen. For posterity: Bazel's language support is highly extensible, and even if certain languages are implemented natively and more difficult to make changes for, there's nothing preventing users from creating their own language support rules for Bazel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here's an outline of how to do it.

Add a custom provider for tracking module information:

```
ModuleCompileInfo = provider(doc = "", fields = [
    "module_name", 
    "module_file",
    "module_dependencies",
])
```

Add a custom rule `cc_module` for producing C++20 modules. Then you can write something like

```
cc_module(
   name = "A",
   src = "a.cc", # a.cc exports the module A
   impl_srcs = [
     "a_impl1.cc", # optionally you can provide additional implementation sources for A
     "a_impl2.cc",
   ],
   deps = [
     ":B", # dependencies can be either other modules or other cc_libraries
     ":C",
   ],
)
```

The custom rule will

1. Create a module map for the module dependencies of A
2. Produce both a static library packaging A's objects and a cmi file for A's module
3. Return both a [CcInfo](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/CcInfo.html) provider for A and a ModuleCompileInfo provider to track the module information.

Because other standard bazel rules (e.g. cc_binary, cc_library), aren't aware of c++20 modules, you also need to provide custom cc_module_binary and cc_module_library rules so that you can make use of modules with other C++ constructs. For example,

```
cc_module_binary(
   name = "exe",
   srcs = ["main.cc"],  # main.cc can import A
   deps = [":A"],       # we can depend on modules
)
```

See https://github.com/rnburn/rules_cc_module for a project that provides c++20 module rules. And see [here](https://github.com/rnburn/rules_cc_module/tree/main/example) for examples of how to use it.